# attr_reader, attr_accessor feature not working as expected

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables, attr

I just finished reading the first few chapters of [POODR](http://www.poodr.com).  The author showcases a feature of attr_reader(accessor) which allows you to eliminate the need for the '@' when referencing instance variables after declaring them, in addition to the better known features of attr_.

However, with GuessingGame#solved? the code only works if I reference the most recent 'guess' using '@guess', not simply 'guess' as I was expecting.  My inclination is that I have a method #guess as well and Ruby is thinking I am calling the method?  Is this correct?

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

```
class GuessingGame
  attr_reader :answer
  attr_accessor :guess

  def initialize(answer)
    answer.is_a?(Integer) ? (@answer = answer) : (raise ArgumentError.new "You must enter an Integer.")
  end

  def guess(guess)
    @guess = guess
    if guess > answer
      :high
    elsif guess < answer
      :low
    else
      :correct
    end
  end

  def solved?
    @guess == answer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.

The code:

```
attr_accessor :guess
```

is equivalent to:

```
def guess
  @guess
end

def guess=(new_value)
  @guess = new_value
end
```

That is, it creates a method which fetches the value of the instance variable and another method which sets the value of the instance variable.

When you **redefine** the method `guess` later, it **overwrites** the method defined implicitly by `attr_accessor`:

```
def guess
  3
end

def guess
  4
end

guess
#=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So, if I change the instance variable 'guess' to attr_reader or change the name of the method in the class, it will remedy the situation you're describing?

Comment: The method `attr_accessor :guess` in effect is the exact same as `attr_reader :guess ; attr_writer :guess`. You just can't have two methods with the same name in the same scope - Ruby will get rid of the first method by that name and replace it with the second.